# What is a "Holders/Sujetadores de Sujecion"?

Tags: tools

I bought a package of locking peg hooks at Home Depot, along with some pegboard and other assorted stuff. When I got home, I hung up the pegboard. It fit just fine. I then attempted to attach my new peg hooks.

However, I didn't get far. After having used up the majority of the tools, I came to a part that the box identified as "Holders/Sujetadores de Sujecion". Well, that didn't help much. I searched the Internet and that was [even](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=how%20to%20use%20%22holders%22%20everbilt%20locking%20peg%20hook%20assortment) [less](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22holders%22%20everbilt%20locking%20peg%20hook%20assortment) [successful](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=%22holders%22%20everbilt). Even [the company name](http://duckduckgo.com/?q=everbilt) couldn't be found. And the URL [everbilt.com](http://everbilt.com) redirected [here](http://www.eclipseshutters.com/).

The only other useful info on the box is "Eb Everbilt" and "Locking Peg Hook Assortment"

Ugh!

What are these "Holders/Sujetadores de Sujecion" and how can I use them?

P.S. Pictures coming soon!

Comment: The black plastic clips are called "Peg Locks." I am also trying to find out how to use the pegboard "Holder."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are referring to the black plastic clips that come with the assorted pegboard hooks from Home Depot.  "Sujetadores de Sujecion" is Spanish for "Fastening Clips". These are placed over the hook to hold it to the board - this is useful for the single hole hooks that tend to come out easily. I found that these do not fit all pegboards.  They are not essential by any means.